# strange character at the top right of the page

Tags: symbols

I found a kind of x symbol at the top right of the page: https://www.tothetoptogether.it/iscriviti/

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on Stack Overflow! I encourage you to write as many details as you can in your questions, so that other users can help you in the best possible way. As for the question, I think it’s just a typo. Inspecting the source code of the page, I find `x` seems to be a “lost” character:

[image]

If you have access to the source code of the page, deleting it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately i can't because i use Elementor. You are right

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please check it as the correct answer with the ✓ on its left.